# Kendo Sortable / how to get sorted array or sort the scope array values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, sorting

I have table which is filled using the AngularJS **ng-repeat** loop from data in array of objects in the scope.

After that is on the table applied sortable feature from the kendo UI.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/sortable#methods-items

I can sort rows in table and I would like to get sorder array of the items in the scope after the **end:**  event.

I tried to do it by this way, but without luck:

Could somebody tell me how can i solve it please?

Many Thanks for any advice.

```
 $scope.makeExistingEntriesSortable = function() {
        var sortable = $("#forecastsTable").kendoSortable({
            end: function(e) {
                console.log("from " + e.oldIndex + " to " + e.newIndex);
                console.log(sortable);
                //prevent first item to be placed at the end of the list
                if(e.newIndex == 2 && e.oldIndex == 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            },
            disabled: "disabled",
            hint : function(element) {
                console.log(element.position);
                element = element.clone().addClass("hint");
                return element
            },
            placeholder : function(element) {
                console.log(element.position);
                element = element.clone().addClass("placeholder").text("drop here");
                return element;
            },
            handler: ".handlerForecasts"
        });
        console.log("Table should be now sortable");
        /*
        // MAKE INPUTS FOCUSABLE
        $(".focusedInput").click(function() {
            console.log(this);
            $(this).focus();
        });
    */

    };
```

Comment: if you are using <table> tag to display your data and if sortable functionality is there, just use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable. Its just awesome. once you pick and drop your row, it automatically updates your model.

Comment: Thank you, it works exactly as i need.

Comment: great enjoy redrom !